# Locking issues with Oracle update statement

Tags: sql, sql-update

My below query getting stuck\hang after commit, how to fix?

```
for i in tail -"$b" Locked.csv |cut -c1-7
do
sqlplus -s $TOA_DB <<! &2>1
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
update admsvc_lockinfo_t
set login_atmpts = 0, lock_status = 0 where obj_id0 in
(select POID_ID0 from service_t where login ='$i');

update service_t set PASSWD_STATUS =0  where login ='$i';

commit;

exit
```

Comment: what error related to locking it shows ....

Comment: my program getting hang after commit as other user updating the same table but not commited.

Comment: also my programe never stuck when one row need to update it stuck in case of multiple user(more then one row to update)